Which regression should I use to estimate the covariance?
I generated some synthetic data using the following code. I want to infer U using only the information from (X, Z, Y). For example, Poisson regression estimates the mean of U but doesn't provide information about its covariance. Which regression model would be appropriate?
# Load necessary package
library(lme4)
library(MASS)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Generate X
X <- 1 + rnorm(10000, 0, 1)
beta <- 0.5

# Generate Z
Z <- 0.2 * matrix(rnorm(20000), ncol = 2)

# Mean vector and covariance matrix
mean <- c(-0.5, 1)
covariance_matrix <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5), nrow = 2)

# Sampling from the multivariate normal distribution
U <- mvrnorm(10000, mu = mean, Sigma = covariance_matrix)

# Compute linear combination
linear <- X * beta + rowSums(Z * U)

# Sampling from the Poisson distribution
rate <- exp(linear)
Y <- rpois(10000, lambda = rate)

# Organize into a data frame
data <- data.frame(X = X, Z1 = Z[,1], Z2 = Z[,2], Y = Y)

example_model = glm(Y ~ 0 + X + Z1 + Z2, data = data, family = poisson)

My try:
data$id = 1:nrow(data)
model = glmer(Y ~ 0 + X + Z1 + Z2 + (0 + Z1 + Z2 | id), data = data, family = poisson,
                control=glmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore",
                                     check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore",
                                     check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))

While this works, the overall quality was not good. Any idea?

What is U here?

@dimitriy U is a sample from a bivariate normal distribution. Check
U <- mvrnorm(10000, mu = mean, Sigma = covariance_matrix)

A better way to ask my question is what it and its covariance represents. It seems like it is a hybrid of an constant and an random error process.

@dimitriy General regression estimates the coefficients of covariates, which are just numbers. However, in my case, I am considering a situation with randomness in the coefficients and a correlation structure among the coefficients. In other words, estimation aims to understand the information about the random variables. Here, U is just created as true noise for simulation purposes (I'm not sure if this is the correct term). Because I am not a statistician, I am curious about what modeling statisticians use in such situations.

That makes more sense now. The variance-covariance matrix for the coefficients contains the covariances between them in the off-diagonal cells. The coefficient standard errors are the square root of the coefficient variances found on the diagonal. You can see the whole matrix with vcov(example_model).

@dimitriy As far as I know, the vcov() function returns the covariance of the estimated coefficients, not the covariance of U. Even if it did, the value is very small (1.845682e-05) and fails to accurately estimate the actual covariance of U, which is 0.5. It seems that a different model is needed.

The coefficients are random variables, too, but you want an estimate of sigma. This is much harder and probably impossible.

@dimitriy How about my try (using GLMM)?
